# spring batch program for MYSQL - copy data from one db to another

Tags: database, spring, oracle, batch-file, synchronization

currently looking for a example program for copying data from one db to another on oracle (DB sync up) & I'm trying to do this by spring batch ??
Got examples for MYSQL to Flat file & vice versa but not for oracle DB to DB .... Need some help on this 
Found this in Datasource configuration file , have to set it to work with Oracle is it possible ?

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:schema-all.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Please post any code you've tried, you'll be more likely to get a response - shows you've at least had a go and done some research.  have you tried googling?

Comment: There are lots of applications that do exactly that. Why do you need to write it by yourself?

Comment: actually ,I'm looking for sync up between DB's which reads rows changed on one DB & then updates the same on another DB which contains the same field tables

Answer (score 0):

copying data from one db to another on oracle . 
is both DB is oracle ? in that case you can use DB Link to copy data from one oracle DB to other oracle DB.

if want to copy data from non-oracle DB to Oracle DB then use "External table" . External table is best approach. From non-oracle DB you have export data in coma separated text file and in oracle DB use External table to load the data into DB.

Comment: from Online sources I heard that for scheduling jobs , Spring batch would be useful so  looking for a Spring batch program example